# Sympy computing the inverse laplace transform

Tags: python, sympy, symbolic-math

I am having some trouble computing the inverse laplace transform of a symbolic expression using sympy. In matlab and in the book I am working from the expression s/(s^2 + w^2) transforms to cos(wt).

When I attempt to do this using sympy like so:

```
expression = s/(s**2+w**2)
Answer = sympy.inverse_laplace_transform(expression, s, t)
```

I get that

```
Answer = (-I*exp(2*t*im(w))*sin(t*re(w)) + exp(2*t*im(w))*cos(t*re(w)) + I*sin(t*re(w)) + cos(t*re(w)))*exp(-t*im(w))*Heaviside(t)/2
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Sympy assumes that `w` is complex-valued. The simpler approach is to provide the option `real=True` in the definition of the symbol.

```
s, t = sp.symbols('s, t')
w = sp.symbols('w', real = True)
expression = s/(s**2+w**2)

sympy.inverse_laplace_transform(expression, s, t)
```

> `cos(t*w)*Heaviside(t)`

Comment: You can also do `t = sp.Symbol('t', positive=True)` if you don't want the `Heaviside(t)`. Positive also implies real.